# How to open the same access form in both editable and non-editable mode in different scenarios

Tags: ms-access

I am working with forms in Access 2010. I have two requirements for the same form which are activities done by two different people. One enters data into the form and the other checks data. The person entering the data can't edit already available records. The person editing records can open the data and edit the details. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are opening the form with code using [Docmd.Openform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238021%28v=office.12%29.aspx), you can set `DataMode` to `acFormAdd`, which will make it so that the form can only have new records added. Alternately, you can use `acFormEdit` to indicate edits and new records and be done.

If you are opening the form directly, you can set the option when the form opens.

If you want the form to only allow new records do something like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If 'your condition then
        Me.DataEntry = True
    end if
End Sub
```